# The difference between "sich xyz stellen", and "sich xyz anstellen"

Tags: meaning, difference, german-to-english

I was wondering if you could help be figure out the difference between the two sentences.

1. > Er stellt sich dumm.
2. > Er stellt sich dumm an.

I think the first sentence is translated as, "He's playing/acting dumb", as "sich tot stellen" is to "play dead". But every dictionary that I look at gives pretty much the same translation for "sich dumm anstellen".

Where is the difference between the two?

Comment: It should be noted that *er stellt sich XYZ* works for a couple of adverbs, for example *dumm*, *tot* or *taub*, but not for others. For example, you can not say *er stellt sich schnell* or *er stellt sich intelligent*. In some cases *er stellt sich XYZ an* does work, however, for example *er stellt sich intelligent an*.

Comment: It should also be noted that *Er stellt sich XYZ* also works with nouns and names, like *Er stellt sich seinem Feind* or *Er stellt sich der Polizei*. In these cases, the meaning is totally different. Depending on context, it could mean *He confronted his enemy* or *He surrendered to the police*.

Answer (score 8):

The first emphasizes *pretense* in an action; the second emphasizes the *effect* of the action. Therefore, "sich stellen" is always intentional fakery; "sich anstellen" may not be.

To clarify:

> Bei der Fahrprüfung stellte er sich ziemlich dumm an.

*could* describe someone who intentionally fails a driving test (for some unspeified purpose). But it's much more likely that the driver was simply nervous, incapacitated or otherwise impaired and failed despite being fundamentally capable.

In contrast,

> Er stellte sich dumm.

definitely means that someone knows more than they let on.

Answer (score 7):

This is simple:

> Er stellt sich dumm.
>   He pretends/plays to be stupid.  Or
>   He pretends not to know anything.

This means he acts and behaves in a way that other people might think he is stupid, although he really isn't.

> Er stellt sich dumm an.
>   He acts awkward/clumsy/unadept.

This means, that he is doing something in a manner that is not skillful or not intelligent. This is not played. He really can't do it better.

**Examples:**

- sich dumm stellen

  > Wenn du mit der Presse sprichst, darfst du nichts über die Sache in Manila ausplaudern. Wenn man dich darauf ansprichst, musst du dich dumm stellen.
  >   When you talk to the press, don't talk about the matter in Manila. If they address it, you must act unaware.
- sich dumm anstellen

  > Jürgen ist ein eigentlich ein sehr intelligenter und kluger junger Mann, aber wenn es um Mädchen geht, stellt er sich furchtbar dumm an.
  >   Jürgen is actually a very intelligent and smart young man, but when it comes to girls, he behaves terribly stupid.